# Rails i18n helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-i18n

Rails helpers require me to have a i18n key for every model that I have. Example:

```
en:
    helpers:
        label:
            employee:
                email: 'E-mail'
                password: 'Password'
                remember_me: 'Remember me'
```

Is there a way to set default values for these keys?

I tried something like the following without success:

```
en:
    helpers:
        label:
            email: 'E-mail'
            password: 'Password'
            remember_me: 'Remember me'

en:
    helpers:
        label:
            default:
                email: 'E-mail'
                password: 'Password'
                remember_me: 'Remember me'

en:
    helpers:
        label:
            defaults:
                email: 'E-mail'
                password: 'Password'
                remember_me: 'Remember me'
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achieved what I needed using [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form).

```
pt-BR:
    simple_form:
        labels:
            defaults:
                email: E-mail
                password: Senha
                remember_me: Lembrar de mim
```